# Spring multiple mappings for angular application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I saw a lot of similar questions, but it seems like none of the answers work!

So after compilation of my angular 4 app (which creates an index.html and a bunch of .bundle.js files), I've placed them in the static folder of my Spring Boot application. So if I run the Spring app on port 8000, I can see my home page at localhost:8000.

Now, what I want to do, is to **also** go to my homepage if I enter localhost:8000/lite. In addition, I **do not** want a redirect, I want the homepage to be visible and the URL in the browser to be localhost:8000/lite.

How should I go about that? If there is a working solution in SO, please link and I will delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is a little difficult get all together! Because you have the Angular4 routing on frontend and Java routing on backend. In your case, only java is routing. because `/lite` will not return the HTML content.

When you do `/lite`, you java server will look for it's implementation of `/lite`, so every HTML 5 routing you will need to send `index.html` as response.

I believe the best approach is organize:

1. `/api/` you java code will handle
2. `/resources` all frontend resources you have
3. `*` send `index.html` as content response and let it handle everything

---

For handle all request, try:

```
@RequestMapping(value="**",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAnythingelse(){
    return "redirect:/index.html";
}
```

Comment: Right - this is already the structure I have. My question is more about the technical side for 3. Can you give me sample code I can use in spring boot to send "index.html" as the content response inside a controller?

Comment: I found the code above here in stackoverflow! Maybe it will works, but is something like that.